# How to install Google Play services on an Android 6.0 emulator?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, android-emulator, google-play-services

Is there a way to install Google Play app on an Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) AVD?
I have found the Open Gapps for Android 6 here:
https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24269982087008996

To install them you need to boot into Recovery mode and install that zip file, but
an emulator does not have a recovery partition, so the steps target the case of a
device.

Do you know, how I can do the same for the emulator? I tried to unzip the file and
put the 4 APKs described here (for Android version 5):
http://www.flinkd.org/2015/02/instal...i-21-lollipop/

but after rebooting the emulator, although the icon of Google Play appears in the launcher,
when I tap on it, then the emulator crashes with some fatal exceptions in logcat.
I tried to install the packages one at a time, rebooting the emulator after each installation,
and found out that the crash happens after installing the Phonesky.apk no matter if you
click on the Google Play icon.

Comment: Just an idea (untested): Check my app list for [Custom Recovery & Flashing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_1016). Flashify was one of the apps intended to take-over such tasks from recovery, so one can flash without booting to recovery. Might work in an Emu as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I will check it out! :)

Comment: Don't forget to update us with the results, please! :)

Comment: I tried to do `adb shell stop && adb shell start` since I am on an emulator
and a reboot would flash the system.img, but the emulator hangs on the
boot animation. Moreover, I tried to tap on the reboot button but
again the emulator got frozen in the rebooting screen with theloading icon..

Comment: Maybe the files in the zip contain errors. I will try some other zip files as well I found on other web pages. Logcat doesn't seem to provide enough information about this.. I will let you know.

Comment: I tried with this one: http://downloadmirror.co/android/ug/open_gapps-arm-6.0-pico-20151113.zip and if I tap the reboot button, again it gets frozen. But when I do the `adb shell stop && adb shell start` commands it reboots successfully. There is no Google Play icon on the launcher screen though.

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution?

Comment: @ThanasisPetsas Were you able to install play store on emulator? And then install another app from playstore?

Answer (score 9):

1) Go get GApps for the emulator from http://opengapps.org

2) Unzip to get

- GmsCore.apk
- GoogleServicesFramework.apk
- GoogleLoginService.apk
- Phonesky.apk

Launch the emulator from the command line, on linux you do

```
./emulator [name] -no-boot-anim -writable-system
```

on windows it's probably

```
emulator.exe [name] -no-boot-anim -writable-system
```

Make sure you have adb access to the emulator.

```
adb remount
```

last but not least, push everything to system.

```
adb push GmsCore.apk /system/priv-app/
```

(and repeat for all the other APKs)

then reboot with

```
adb shell stop
```

and

```
adb shell start
```

Comment: This does not work. This error appears all the time: `adb: error: failed to copy 'Phonesky.apk' to '/system/priv-app/Phonesky.apk': Read-only file system`. No remount in any way does help, as the output of every remount is the following: `mount: Read-only file system`. Yeah, thanks android, thats why I want to remount it with rw -.-

Comment: In the same boat as @ChristianDreher - can't write to the filesystem. adb remount succeeds, and pushing after that gets a little bit of the way then stops. I can't remount from an adb shell either. Any ideas?

Comment: I've had this problem countless times in the past, and it astounds me that the solution isn't more widely known. Simply start the emulator with the -writable-system argument. Hey presto, writable system partition, and these instructions suddenly work.

Comment: To avoid `Read-only file system` error you should start an emulator with `-writable-system` flag

Comment: After doing steps in this answer my emulator would not power on.

Comment: Running `emulator -shell` open shell prompt with root permission