# Install Google Play on Android SDK Emulator

Tags: google-play-store, android-emulator, google-play-services

How can I install google play on the Android SDK Emulator? I start my emulator like this:

```
./emulator -avd my_custom_device_API_26 -dns-server 8.8.8.8 -writable-system
```

and I tried it [How to install Google Play services on an Android 6.0 emulator?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131100/how-to-install-google-play-services-on-an-android-6-0-emulator), but it doesn't work. Although I'm staring emulator as writable, I get:

```
remote couldn't create file: Read-only file system
```

Also, I've bit different APKs as mentioned in that answer namely: `PrebuiltGmsCorePix.apk` instead `GmsCore.apk` and I can't find `GoogleLoginService.apk`. I have the Open GApps 8.1 Pico version. I've also tried to install APKs but was unsuccessful.

Comment: You need to elevate to root access to mount RW. Try `adb root` then `adb remount` then push and install your package.

Answer (score 5):

For that, you have to install the Google Play image from the Android Studio SDK Manager. But you can't get it for API level below 24

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remember that to display all those submenus you have to tick `Show Package Details` on `Android SDK` setting:

[image]

Also the download may be about 2GB but on hard drive may take 10GB once decompressed.

Answer (score 1):

Other comments don't mention it, but after installing the Google Play you also need to create an emulator again (there will be +Store in the description)
[image]

Comment: Hiya! Make sure when answering that you're still giving a full solution to the question being asked. For situations like this, it's common to point to other answers as what to follow for a setup, then continue with the extra details you feel are necessary.